# Swift Compiler Error - Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I've been getting this error for quite some time though after a few attempts at building and running the project, it worked. Now, however, I am not able to build the project at all. I'm currently using Fabric and Firebase which I read somewhere may be related.

The error shows the following:
http://pastebin.com/KiyK6qd6

I'm also using Swift 3